# PHP5.4 on Windows, with sqlite but without Apache and MySQL

Tags: php, sqlite, xampp, wamp

Prefer to install minimum software to reduce disk and memory footprint. Thus, I plan to install a minimalistic PHP+DB configuration. Here's my idea of minimalistic setup, as opposed to a full-scale WAMP stack:

- PHP5.4.x binaries (use the inbuilt webserver, instead of Apache)
- SQLite (instead of MySQL)

I would like to manually start-stop the PHP web-server (i.e. not run it as a auto-started service). There are many tutorials and instructions about setup of WAMP alternatives using NGINX, MariaDB, PostgreSQL etc., but I've not found anything with the above configuration. This is a development and learning setup. I plan to use a micro-framework (like Slim) at some point, to develop REST based application (rather learn to do so), which shall serve as the backend (again, in development mode) for Android applications.

Would like to understand:

- If I'd be missing some key capabilities (compared to a WAMP/LAMP stack) with the above minimalistic approach ?
- Any existing guide / tutorial that explains how to create such a minimalistic setup ?

Comment: Request people to cite reasons before voting to close it.

Answer (score 1):

Look into using QuickPHP (http://www.zachsaw.com/?pg=quickphp_php_tester_debugger). It's a tiny php server for Windows which comes with just the php dll. Or you can download the php binaries for windows and place the QuickPHP executable there and then enable extensions like SQLite by changing the php ini configuration files. Note that it's meant for development and debugging purposes only.